# Php Login issue

Tags: php

Following is my php login script, There are one problem. If i put any password then it's doesn't validate the password and it's going to user panel page. where is the wrong in my code, can anyone tell me the right direction

N:B: I'M NEW IN PHP ALSO NEW IN THIS SITE.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['action']) == 'Log In')
{
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['uname']))); 
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass'])));   

$crytpass = hash('sha512','$pass'); 
$err = array();

include_once("toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");

// check username 
$check_uname = mysql_query("SELECT uname FROM members WHERE uname = '$uname'");
$num_uname = mysql_num_rows($check_uname);

// check password
$check_pass = mysql_query("SELECT pass FROM members WHERE pass = '$crytpass'");
$num_pass = mysql_num_rows($check_pass);

/// userid

$userid = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM members");    
$re = mysql_fetch_array($userid);
$userid = (int) $re['userid'];


if(isset($uname) && isset($pass))
{
    if(empty($uname) && empty($pass))   
        $err[] = "All field required";  
    else
    {
        // username validation process....

        if(empty($uname))
            $err[] = "Username required";
        else
        {
            if($num_uname == 0)         
            $err[] = "Username is not correct";
        }

        // password validaiton process...

        if(empty($pass))
            $err[] = "Password required";               
        else
        {
            if($num_pass == 0)
            $err[] = "Password is not correct";         
        }

    }
}

if(!empty($err))
{
    foreach($err as $er)
    {
        echo "<font color=red>$er<br></font>";
    }   
}
else
{   
     include("user/include/newsession.php");                   
         header("Location:user/index.php");                     

}

}
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to read up on some PHP basics. I think you understand the basic idea, you just need to figure out when to use what function for what purpose.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing three different queries to get data from your `members` table?!  You're selecting a field you already have in the first query, some (not necessarily related) user's encrypted password in the next query, and then you're selecting *every single userid* in your members table.

Comment: You should do 1 query to check all posted values, ditch this code and start again..

Comment: @Crontab I'm new in php, thanks for your advise..

Comment: `if(empty($uname) && empty($pass))` should be `if(empty($uname) || empty($pass))` Otherwise the statement gives TRUE when you leave one empty

Comment: @user1295995: It's not really just a PHP thing, it's a "working with relational databases" thing, and sort of a basic logic thing, too.  Write out what you want your code to do, verify that it makes sense and you're not adding a bunch of extra steps, THEN write the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many thing are wrong here

Replace

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['action'] ) && isset ( $_POST ['action'] ) == 'Log In') {
```

With

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['action'] ) &&  $_POST ['action'] == 'Log In') {
```

Too many things to replace .. hold on while i rewrite the script for you

**Edit 1**

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['action'] ) && $_POST ['action'] == 'Log In') {
    $uname = prepareStr ( $_POST ['uname'] );
    $pass = prepareStr ( $_POST ['pass'] );
    $shaPass = hash ( 'sha512', $pass );
    $errors = array ();

    include_once ("toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");

    if (! isset ( $uname ) || empty ( $uname )) {
        $err [] = "Empty Username not allowed";
    }

    if (! isset ( $pass ) || empty ( $pass )) {
        $err [] = "Empty Password not allowed";
    }

    if (count ( $err ) == 0) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli ( "localhost", "root", "", "test" ); // Replace with
                                                                  // DB
                                                                  // Information
        $result = "SELECT uname ,pass FROM members WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass = '$shaPass'";

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $err [] = "Invalid username or Password";
        }

        if (count ( $err ) == 0 && $result) {
            $userInfo = $result->fetch_assoc ();
        /**
         * You can do what every you like here
         */
        }
    }

    if (count ( $err ) > 0) {
        /**
         * Kill the user
         */

        echo "<pre>";

        foreach ( $err as $value ) {
            echo $value . "\n";
        }
        die ( "Die! Die! Die!" );
    }

}

function prepareStr($str) {
    $str = htmlspecialchars ( $str );
    $str = trim ( $str );
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string ( $str );

    return $str;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot , @Baba I'm waiting...

Comment: +1 @Hans Wassink  for the recognition

Comment: Haha +1 @Baba for recognising recognition. And an infinite loop was born

Comment: Lol @Hans  don't crash the server pleaseeeeeeeeeeeee :D

Comment: One more question @Baba..after successfully login.. is it necessary to register uname, password and userid with session?

Comment: And Also.. It's given two error message: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\signin.php on line 42

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\signin.php on line 48

Comment: Yes .... but only the hashed password .. you can use this in your code of to verify user at different times during certain operations .... make sure you accept so that people can know its resolved

Comment: Now it's given two error message...

Comment: what is the error message ???

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\signin.php on line 42 Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\signin.php on line 48

Comment: Updated .... please test and let me know

Comment: Shouldn't `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` be `if ($result->num_rows == 0)` or `if ($result->num_rows != 1)` or something? Now error message is set even if there is returned row (or rows).

Comment: Put the full content of `signin.php` in pastbin .. let me take a look at the script ....

Comment: Are you sure ... my update has reflected ????

Comment: @ZZ-bb if `if ($result->num_rows > 0)` is valid ... it means if the `number of rows` is `not equal to zero` , `not equal to false` but `grater than 0`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt tell your users if the username was wrong, this makes it easier for brute force attemps to break in.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'Log In') {
    $userid = false;
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['uname'])));
    // or better
    // $uname = filter_var($_POST['uname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];   

    $crytpass = hash('sha512',$pass); 
    $err = array();

    include_once("toplevel/content/manage/dbcon/dbcon.php");

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM members WHERE uname = '$uname' AND pass='$cryptpass'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0){
        $re = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        $userid = (int) $re['userid'];
    } else {
        // username or password wrong
    )

   if($userid) {
      // successfull login
   }
```

}